# Jenkins Pipeline Run Stage On Failure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

My Jenkins pipline script has a lot of try/catch blocks to notify me when there is a failure. Is it possible to have a stage that will only run if a previous stage fails?

My current script looks something like this.

```
stage('Stage 1') {
    steps {
        try {
            // do something
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'FAILED')
            error 'FAILED'
        }
    }
}
stage('Stage 2') {
    steps {
        try {
            // do something
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'FAILED')
            error 'FAILED'
        }
    }
}
stage('Stage 3') {
    steps {
        try {
            // do something
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'FAILED')
            error 'FAILED'
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do something like this.

```
stage('Stage 1') {
    steps {
        // do something
    }
}
stage('Stage 2') {
    steps {
        // do something
    }
}
stage('Stage 3') {
    steps {
        // do something
    }
}
stage('Only Run On Failure') {
    steps {
        bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'FAILED')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To notify failures on any stage across your pipeline, use [post actions](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post). 
For each pipeline result, you can then set some post actions.

Example for unsuccessful(any build that does not end with 'SUCCESS' result):

```
stages{
    stage('Stage 1') {
        steps {
            // do something
        }
    }
    stage('Stage 2') {
        steps {
        // do something
        }
    }
    stage('Stage 3') {
        steps {
            // do something
        }  
    }
post{
    success{
        bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'SUCCESS')
    } 
    unsuccessful{
        bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'FAILED')
    }    
}
```

Comment: The when block is useful, but I'm trying to get rid of the try catch blocks to clean the script up and get rid of code duplication. Jenkins knows when a step fails and will skip to the end reporting a build failure. I figured there was some way to check that without setting a flag manually.

Comment: Hi Sal, I understood that you wanted to run all 3 stages, whatever is their result. If you want to discard the remaining stages, if one fails, and notify upon its failure, you should use [post actions](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post).

Comment: Post actions is what I was looking for thanks. Can you update your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Updated accordingly. Let me know if that's not fine. Thank you Sal.